# Trying to upload image using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

can anybody help me? I' m trying to upload an image using jquery and laravel but don't know how to pass the data

**Ajax Function**

```
var form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('link', link);
form_data.append('comment', comment);
form_data.append('reportid', reportid);

$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('report.update') }}",
    type:"GET",
    data:form_data,
    contentType:false,
    cache:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('report-update', ['uses'=>'Executive@reportUpdate', 'as'=>'report.update']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function reportUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');

    echo $file->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

Comment: Change type `GET` to `POST`, and change your Route too

Comment: Firstly,your route is wrong, it should be POST.
And you cannot directly send a file via AJAX like this. What you can do is upload the file using some other methods  and pass the name or path of file in your form data..
You can use libraries like blueimp  (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload )to upload the file , and then pass the return file data in AJAX

Answer (score 0):

add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

```
$.ajax({

    url:"{{ route('report.update') }}",
    type:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }

});
```

```
 Route::POST('report-update', ['uses'=>'Executive@reportUpdate', 'as'=>'report.update']);
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
var formData = new FormData($("#formid")[0]);
$.ajax({
   url: "{{ route('report.update') }}",
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: formData,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
   cache: false,
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       console.log(data)
   }
});
```

and use form method is **POST**

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

```
 $("#FormId").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('report.update') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
            }


        })
    }));
```

**Route**

```
Route::POST('report-update', ['uses'=>'Executive@reportUpdate', 'as'=>'report.update']);
```

**Function**

```
public function reportUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $fileName = time().$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path=$file->move('FolderPath',$fileName);
}
```